# Getting indentation errors on Python code can't resolve indents

Tags: python, eclipse

I am getting an error with this code. I'm trying to add a buff when I use a combat command. It just seems to be messed up with indentation errors. I'm remaking the game [Star Wars Galaxies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Galaxies).

#### Code

```
import sys

def setup(core, actor, target, command):
    command.setBuffNameTarget('of_deb_def_1')
if actor.getSkill('expertise_of_advanced_paint_1'):
    command.setBuffNameTarget('of_adv_paint_debuff_1')
if actor.getSkill('expertise_of_paint_expose_1'):
    command.setBuffNameTarget('of_adv_paint_expose_1')
    return

def preRun(core, actor, target, command):
    return

def run(core, actor, target, commandString):
    return
```

#### Error

```
File "scripts/commands/combat/of_deb_def_1.py", line 5
if actor.getSkill('expertise_of_advanced_paint_1'):
^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

`^` is the error I get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from anything else, the code here:

```
if actor.getSkill('expertise_of_advanced_paint_1'):
    command.setBuffNameTarget('of_adv_paint_debuff_1')
if actor.getSkill('expertise_of_paint_expose_1'):
    command.setBuffNameTarget('of_adv_paint_expose_1')
    return
```

needs to be indented. Corrected code:

```
def setup(core, actor, target, command):
    command.setBuffNameTarget('of_deb_def_1')
    if actor.getSkill('expertise_of_advanced_paint_1'):
        command.setBuffNameTarget('of_adv_paint_debuff_1')
    if actor.getSkill('expertise_of_paint_expose_1'):
        command.setBuffNameTarget('of_adv_paint_expose_1')
        return
```

Also, you may want to dedent `return`, or remove it entirely as currently it has no effect.

But I'm unsure if this is the problem, although it is certainly *a* problem (unless the whole code you have given is itself inside another function definition, which would seem odd in this situation).

Failing that, I suspect you have either indented your code wrongly when posting it here, or mixed tabs and spaces (don't do that).

Comment: @sweeneyrod, you might want to show the correct indentation for `def setup` too

Comment: alright it seems to work now just have to change a parameter or two but thanks for your help

Comment: @user2674430 If an answer answered your question it would be good to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to assure that you did not mix up spaces and tabs, you can use [tabnanny](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tabnanny.html). For using it, simply go with your terminal into the directory where your file is saved and execute it:

```
>>> python -m tabnanny .
```

This example is taken from Python Module of the Week: http://pymotw.com/2/tabnanny/

Answer (score 0):

According to the code given, it looks like the 4 lines starting from the first `if actor.getSkill` should fall under the function `setup()`.

```
def setup(core, actor, target, command):
    command.setBuffNameTarget('of_deb_def_1')
    if actor.getSkill('expertise_of_advanced_paint_1'):
        command.setBuffNameTarget('of_adv_paint_debuff_1')
    if actor.getSkill('expertise_of_paint_expose_1'):
        command.setBuffNameTarget('of_adv_paint_expose_1')
    return
```